# Multitouch detection

Tags: iphone

I am developing a game of race type. I have a image for acceleration of car and other image for changing the track as we have 3 lanes.

My problem is that when i am touching the acceleration image and suddenly want to change the track its not detecting the another touch if i am still touching acceleration image. Means multitouch is not getting recognized.

I also used multipleTouchEnabled = true for the two images and also for the view also.

Will any body knows why this is happening. Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vishal.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a direct answer but what I find best to do when things like this happen is narrow down the variables.  Create a new small project and make sure you can get multi-touch working there first and then move over to the real project.  My guess would be something you're going with animation or views is hindering your ability to use mult-touch. Good luck.